# Privacy concerns related to OpenPGP (Email Encryption) key being searchable on key servers

Tags: thunderbird, privacy, spam-prevention, pgp

I am considering configuring PGP (Pretty Good Privacy) in my Thunderbird email client to enhance the security and privacy of my email communication.

However, I am concerned about potential privacy risks associated with [OpenPGP (Email Encryption)](https://www.openpgp.org/) key being searchable on key servers: If a spammer queries millions of possible email addresses and obtains results for a subset with associated public keys, it could expose those email addresses to spam.

How can I address this concern proactively or implement safeguards? Seeking advice on best practices for managing PGP keys to mitigate the risk of exposure to spammers.

Comment: Unless someone is very frugal with their email address, it has likely already been acquired within the hundreds of data breaches that occur within companies every year. Sure, GPG/PGP key emails are low-hanging fruit, but harvesting emails from GPG/PGP keyservers is low return for a lot of work since there's little value when compared to company databases with usernames and other PII. We use keyservers to make it more convenient for others to send us encrypted info, so it's a personal choice whether that convenience is outweighed by the relatively low-risk of the attached email being harvested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [FAQ](https://pgp.mit.edu/faq.html) of MIT PGP server you will see this:

> **I think spammers got my email address from the PGP keyserver. What can I do?**
> Yes, there have been reports of spammers harvesting
> addresses from PGP keyservers. Unfortunately, there is not much that
> either we or you can do about this. Our best suggestion is you take
> advantage of any spam filtering technology offered by your ISP.